# safari での画面確認

Tags: windows, macos, vpn

mac からVPN接続にてマイクロソフトリモートデスクトップのwindows Chrome環境で開発をしてまして、localhost で立ち上げた画面を　リモート接続元の mac のサファリに確認するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: 「localhost で立ち上げた画面」は web アプリか何かでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうです。WEBアプリになります。

Answer (score 0):

下記の手順で確認できるでしょうか。

1. リモート接続先のWindowsのIPアドレス(A)を調べる
2. WindowsのChromeのアドレスバーに記載されているURL(B)を調べる
3. リモート接続元のMacでSafariを立ち上げる
4. Safariのアドレスバーに(B)のURLを貼り付ける
5. 上記URLの`localhost`を(A)のIPアドレスに書き換える

- 例えば(A)が`http://localhost:8080/hoge/`で、(B)が`192.168.1.2`の場合、書き換え後のURLは`http://192.168.1.2:8080/hoge/`になる

6. Safariで書き換え後のURLにアクセスする

うまく確認できない場合は、どのような事象が発生するのかを質問文に追記してください。
(Safariの画面に「Not Found」エラーページが表示される、など)
また、問題解決のために試みた手順があれば追記してください。
(Windowsのファイアウォールを一時的にすべて無効化した、など)

Comment: microsoft remote desktopで接続した先のWindowsマシンのターミナルからipconfigでIPv4アドレスをコピってリモート接続元のmacのsafariに貼り付けてみましたが　「接続がタイムアウトしました」と出てページ読み込みエラーとなりました。サファリのブラウザには　「xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxのサーバーからの応答が一定時間以内に返ってきませんでした。」と表示されております。